# Subdomain Manage Progrmattically with my application

Tags: windows, spring-mvc, dns, subdomain, plesk

I have one domain exmaple.com with window server and plesk panel.
I have option for register for company and for each company i want to create subdomain or manage option like subdomain.

like

**company1.example.com
company2.example.com**

Can any one tell me best ways for this.
I am create my application with spring and hibernate with tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create aliases for your domain in plesk through API

Client examples https://github.com/sibprogrammer/plesk-api-examples

Request example http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.1/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-rpc/33770.htm:

```
<packet version="1.6.5.0">
    <site-alias>
        <create>
           <site-id>1</site-id>
           <name>company1.example.com</name>
        </create>
    </site-alias>
</packet>
```

Switch on web and tomcat:

```
<packet version="1.6.5.0">
    <site-alias>
        <set>
           <filter>
              <name>company1.example.com</name>
           </filter>
           <settings>
              <pref>
                  <web>1</web>
                  <tomcat>1</tomcat>
              </pref>
           </settings>
        </set>
    </site-alias>
</packet>
```

Note: There is no need `<tomcat>1</tomcat>` on Plesk for Windows